# What's the best way to replace a string inside a string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a bunch of these:

```
'link' => "http://twitter.com/home?status=Check out &quot;{title}&quot; {url}",
```

And Want to replace the {title} and {url} bits.

I'm currently doing this with gsub:

```
l.gsub! "{url}",   URI::encode(@opts[:url])
l.gsub! "{title}", URI::encode(@opts[:title])
```

But I have the feeling there's a much better way to do this than with gsub...

#

This is an edit / addition to clarify:

```
class SocialBookmarkMaker
  require 'open-uri'


  attr_accessor :opts

  def initialize(opts)
    @opts = @@default_opts.merge opts
  end

  @@default_opts = {
    :icon_folder  => "/images/icons/social_aquatic/24 X 24",
    :sites        => ['facebook', 'twitter', 'delicious', 'digg', 'stumbleupon', 'reddit', 'technorati', ],
    :ext          => 'png',
    :url          => 'not provided',
    :title        => 'not provided',
  }

  @@bookmarks = {
    'yahoo' => {
        'name' => 'Yahoo! My Web',
        'link' => 'http://myweb2.search.yahoo.com/myresults/bookmarklet?u={url}&t={title}',
        },
    'google' => {
        'name' => 'Google Bookmarks',
        'link' => 'http://www.google.com/bookmarks/mark?op=edit&bkmk={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'windows' => {
        'name' => 'Windows Live',
        'link' => 'https://favorites.live.com/quickadd.aspx?url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'facebook' => {
        'name' => 'Facebook',
        'link' => 'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}&t={title}',
        },
    'digg' => {
        'name' => 'Digg',
        'link' => 'http://digg.com/submit?phase=2&url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'ask' => {
        'name' => 'Ask',
        'link' => 'http://myjeeves.ask.com/mysearch/BookmarkIt?v=1.2&t=webpages&url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'technorati' => {
        'name' => 'Technorati',
        'link' => 'http://www.technorati.com/faves?add={url}',
        },
    'delicious' => {
        'name' => 'del.icio.us',
        'link' => 'http://del.icio.us/post?url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'stumbleupon' => {
        'name' => 'StumbleUpon',
        'link' => 'http://www.stumbleupon.com/submit?url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'squidoo' => {
        'name' => 'Squidoo',
        'link' => 'http://www.squidoo.com/lensmaster/bookmark?{url}'
        },
    'netscape' => {
        'name' => 'Netscape',
        'link' => 'http://www.netscape.com/submit/?U={url}&T={title}',
        },
    'slashdot' => {
        'name' => 'Slashdot',
        'link' => 'http://slashdot.org/bookmark.pl?url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'reddit' => {
        'name' => 'reddit',
        'link' => 'http://reddit.com/submit?url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'furl'   => {
        'name' => 'Furl',
        'link' => 'http://furl.net/storeIt.jsp?u={url}&t={title}',
        },
    'blinklist' => {
        'name' => 'BlinkList',
        'link' => 'http://blinklist.com/index.php?Action=Blink/addblink.php&Url={url}&Title={title}',
        },
    'dzone' => {
        'name' => 'dzone',
        'link' => 'http://www.dzone.com/links/add.html?url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'swik' => {
        'name' => 'SWiK',
        'link' => 'http://stories.swik.net/?submitUrl&url={url}'
        },
    'shoutwire' => {
        'name' => 'Shoutwrie',
        'link' => 'http://www.shoutwire.com/?p=submit&&link={url}',
        },
    'blinkbits' => {
        'name' => 'Blinkbits',
        'link' => 'http://www.blinkbits.com/bookmarklets/save.php?v=1&source_url={url}',
        },
    'spurl' => {
        'name' => 'Spurl',
        'link' => 'http://www.spurl.net/spurl.php?url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'diigo' => {
        'name' => 'Diigo',
        'link' => 'http://www.diigo.com/post?url={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'tailrank' => {
        'name' => 'Tailrank',
        'link' => 'http://tailrank.com/share/?link_href={url}&title={title}',
        },
    'rawsugar' => {
        'name' => 'Rawsugar',
        'link' => 'http://www.rawsugar.com/tagger/?turl={url}&tttl={title}&editorInitialized=1',
        },
    'twitter' => {
        'name' => 'Twitter',
        'link' => "http://twitter.com/home?status=Check out &quot;{title}&quot; {url}",
        },
  }
  def self.bookmarks
    @@bookmarks
  end

  def icon_loc(site)
    "http://common-resources.---.net.s3.amazonaws.com#{@opts[:icon_folder]}/#{site}.#{@opts[:ext]}"
  end
  def link_url(site)
    l = SocialBookmarkMaker.bookmarks[site]['link']
    l.gsub! "{url}",   URI::encode(@opts[:url])
    l.gsub! "{title}", URI::encode(@opts[:title])
    l
  end

end
```

shared/social_bookmarks/standard.html.haml

```
- opts ||= {}
- opts.merge! :url => request.url
- opts.merge! :title => "---.net: #{@layout[:social_bookmark_title] || @layout[:title] || default_view_title}"

- b = SocialBookmarkMaker.new opts 

- b.opts[:sites].each do |site|
  = link_to(image_tag( b.icon_loc(site) ), b.link_url(site), :title => "Share on #{SocialBookmarkMaker.bookmarks[site]['name']}")
```

I then call this like this in my rails layout:

```
render :partial => "shared/social_bookmarks/standard", :locals => { :opts => {:icon_folder  => "/images/icons/social_aquatic/48 X 48" }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you change your string to look like

```
"http://twitter.com/home?status=Check out &quot;%{title}&quot; %{url}"
```

and then use printf with a Hash

```
s = "http://twitter.com/home?status=Check out &quot;%{title}&quot; %{url}"
# you can of course use @opts as the Hash here.
s = s % {:title => "abc", :url => "def"} # => "http://twitter.com/home?status=Check out &quot;abc&quot; def"
```

and accept that it only works with Ruby 1.9.2 and upwards, or you continue using gsub but using the block syntax to condense it:

```
s.gsub!(/\{(.+?)\}/) do |m|
  @opts[$1.to_sym]
end
```

Comment: Ah the elusive [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25)!

Answer (score 2):

You can just embed the variables directly in the string

```
'link' => "http://twitter.com/home?status=Check out &quot;#{title}&quot; #{url}"
```

Comment: What do you think are the chances that, while he has multiple of those, they all use the same opts or are sequentially created after opts has been constantly updated? Also, how would that be DRY? :)

Comment: To be completely honest, if he has multiples of that same string and is constantly performing the same operation on it - DRY doesn't even come into the question. I assumed that `opts` was defined within the scope of the string (whether it's a method block, loop or otherwise). Either way, we've both posted string interpolation.

Comment: @@bookmarks is a class variable, so variable interpolation (which assumes a value when the file is loaded, isn't an option. This class will be used to make valid social bookmark links PER PAGE, so the value of #title and #url, are always changing. But I suppose I could make it a method, and pass the vars in. But for other reasons, the var works better for me.